# Solving Euler-equation alike 2nd order DE with disturbing RHS

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For a homework problem, I have to solve

$$ t^2 \ddot{x} - 3 t \dot{x} + 3x  = t^2 $$

which seems quite similar to the Euler Equation, which I would know how to solve, apart from the disturbing $ t^2 $ on the RHS instead of a constant $0$.

How does one approach such types of DE? Would it make a difference if there would be a constant $ a \neq 0$ on the RHS?

Thanks for any directions!

Comment: To answer the last question: it would make a difference. Your choice of the form of particular solution depends on what you have as RHS. For this type of equation, you look for a solution that is a polynomial of the same degree as RHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, an equation of the form:

$$\mathcal{L}(x)=f(t)$$

Where $\mathcal{L}$ denotes some differential operator can be solved by finding the form of a general solution "$y_h(t)$"to the **homogeneous** equation (where the sum of any two solutions is again a solution):

$$\mathcal{L}(y_h)=0$$

And then finding any particular solution $y_p(t)$ that satisfies the **inhomogeneous** equation (where the sum of any two solutions is not necessarily another solution):

$$\mathcal{L}(y_p)=f(t)$$

Then the full solution to the original problem will be $x(t) = y_h(t)+y_p(t)$.

Whilst finding solutions to inhomogeneous problems can usually be approached in a formulaic way, finding particular solutions are usually more of a case by case basis. We frequently call the function $f$ the "forcing" of the equation, and it is frequently best to attempt to find a particular solution by looking for something that "looks like" the forcing, plug it into the left hand side and see if it works.

When the forcing is a polynomial, try plugging in a general polynomial of the same degree into the left hand side $(x=at^2+bt+c)$, and then compare coefficients with the right hand side to determine if there exists some real numbers $(a,b,c)$ such that the equation works.